# How to edit podspec file? edit: command not found

Tags: macos, edit

I have updated a forked dead Framework to Swift 3.

Now I want to create a pod and I've tried to follow the Guides.

```
$ pod spec create Peanut
$ edit Peanut.podspec
$ pod spec lint Peanut.podspec
```

A `.podspec` file, linking to the old git, is existing.

I'm navigating to the correct path using `cd` and `ls` lists the correct `.podspec` file.

But when I enter `edit NAME.podspec` I receive:

> -bash: edit: command not found

I have tried to delete the old file and entered those exact lines. Same error.

```
pod spec create Peanut
edit Peanut.podspec
pod spec lint Peanut.podspec
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with CocoaPods. The error is that you can't find the command `edit`.

You could try `nano Peanut.podspec` or `vi Peanut.podspec` or `open -e Peanut.podspec` or `open -t Peanut.podspec`.

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for writing a concise question with specific reproduction steps!